# Function name must be a string fatal error

Tags: php

I have this Fatal error, I've been staring at my code for hours.. I think it has nothing to do with the name of the function `action_send`, it must be some silly 'missing parenthesis' or something...

can you help me please ?

```
if (...) {}
else if (!historic_exist($id)) {
                action_send($req, '0', (strpos($req['TAG'], 'ADMD') !== false) ? $req['ID_ACT'] : '');
//the error is in this line : 
                    if ((strpos($req['WF'],'Install') !== false) && $req('ID_EQU') !== '')
                action_send($req, '', '0');
                    }
```

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: @b0s3 still having the error :/

Comment: @Loqman `Fatal error: Function name must be a string in \..\file.php on line ..`

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but i think `$req('ID_EQU')` should be `$req['ID_EQU']`.

Comment: Sir, you're not (+1) ^^ `$req` is indeed an array...stupid mistake. Please add an answer so I can accept it. thanks

Comment: It would be nice for a question like this to have the code properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can call functions dynamically using variables. In your code you are using `$req('ID_EQU')` which PHP considers a function call.

But `$req` is an array so PHP parser throws a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in \..\file.php on line ..
```

You must change `$req('ID_EQU')` to `$req['ID_EQU']`.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
if ((strpos($req['WF'],'Install') !== false) && $req('ID_EQU') !== '')
```

to

```
if ((strpos($req['WF'],'Install') !== false) && $req['ID_EQU'] !== '')
```